# Can you get EF method name from mvc-mini-profiler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, mvc-mini-profiler

I am using EF D4.1 atabase first for an MVC 3 project. When I see the SQL for my EF methods, it's hard to know which method generated this SQL.

Next to SQL I see a generic description like this:
ExecuteStoreCommands Execute GetResults System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator b__2

Is there a way to know which line number from a current file caused this call or at least which entity query was executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this by wrapping my EF class into a step, using something like this:

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("MyClass:MyMethod"))
{
   ...
}
```

Not sure if there is a more elegant solution / automatic way to see where the call is made on the stack